# How to Stop Analyze in PostgreSQL Auto Vaccume

Tags: postgresql, autovacuum

Auto Vacuum executes Vacuum and Analyze when the threshold is exceeded. The threshold values are as follows:

- autovacuum_vacuum_threshold + autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor * rows
- autovacuum_analyze_threshold + autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor * rows

In PostgreSQL, is there a way to stop Analyze while keeping Auto Vacuum's Vacuum running automatically?

Comment: What's the real problem you try to solve?

Comment: I don't want to turn it off. I wanted to make sure that batch processing and Analyze do not overlap.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is set `autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor` to its maximum 100 for that table, then it will only be analyzed once 100 times as many rows have been modified as are in the table.

But it is not a smart idea to disable autoanalyze, and you shouldn't do it.

Comment: Thanks. As you said, Of course, I don't want to turn it off. I wanted to make sure that batch processing and Analyze do not overlap.

Comment: Then you can temporarily (!) set `autovacuum_enabled = off` on that table and run `VACUUM` manually as part of the batch job whenever needed.